# SQL Server: Insert if column values are null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am newbie to SQL queries so sorry for this basic question.

I want to insert values into a table where column's value is `null`

I tried following

```
INSERT INTO SystemUsers(FilePath)
If @FilePath IS Null
values('C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\MvcApplication8\MvcApplication8\App_Data\Uploads\Lighthouse.jpg')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO SystemUsers(FilePath)
where FilePath IS Null
values('C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\MvcApplication8\MvcApplication8\App_Data\Uploads\Lighthouse.jpg')
```

But that didn't work, how can I insert default values in a column whether column's values are null?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe what you want is the UPDATE command and not the insert something like this

```
UPDATE SystemUsers
SET FilePath = 'C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\MvcApplication8\MvcApplication8\App_Data\Uploads\Lighthouse.jpg'
WHERE FilePath is null
```

Comment: Thanks @jjchiw, I missed this.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE SystemUsers
    SET FilePath = 'C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\MvcApplication8\MvcApplication8\App_Data\Uploads\Lighthouse.jpg'
WHERE FilePath is null
```

Where clause normaly comes after the operation you are doing.